symmetric diophantine equation with $6$ variables
I want to find every solutions $\{x,y,z\},\{u,v,w\}\subset\mathbb{N}$ with $\{x,y,z\}\neq \{u,v,w\}$, $|\{x,y,z\}|=3=|\{u,v,w\}|$, and they fulfill the following equation
$$(x+y+z)(uv+uw+vw)=(u+v+w)(xy+xz+yz).$$
Is there any way I can get every integer solutions in some parameters? or Is there any way I can simplify this?
note: If $x=u$ and $y=v$, then it can be shown by a direct computation that this implies $z=w$. So, we may assume that $|\{x,y,z\}\cap \{u,v,w\}|\leq 1$.
Some solutions with $|\{x,y,z\}\cap \{u,v,w\}| = 1$ exist, for instance, $\{x,y,z\}=\{30,25,10\},\{u,v,w\}=\{30,15,18\}$ and $\{x,y,z\}=\{26,6,30\},\{u,v,w\}=\{26,11,20\}$.
So, just in case finding every solution is difficult, at least, is there any way to find every solution with an additional constraint: $|\{x,y,z\}\cap \{u,v,w\}| = 1$? (or $|\{x,y,z\}\cap \{u,v,w\}| = 0$)
For the case $|\{x,y,z\}\cap \{u,v,w\}| = 1$, by substituting, let's say, $x=u$ to the equation, we get a quadratic equation on $x$ with coefficients in $v,w,y,z$. But, it is still somehow complicated, so I wonder if there is another way to solve this.

Are $x,y,z$ different integers? If not, $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ is a solution with arbitrary nonzero $u,v,w$. Moreover, just take $x,y,z$ with $x+y+z=0$. Then there are infinitely many distinct $u,v,w$, different from $x,y,z$ with a solution.

Yes, they are distinct. Sorry, I will edit the question.

Oh sorry, I also forgot to mention that $x,y,z,u,v,w$ are positive integers.

There also exist solutions where all numbers $x,y,z,u,v,w$ are distinct positive integers, e.g.,
$$
(x,y,z)=(3,5,41),\quad (u,v,w)=(1,7,49).
$$
This is based on solving first the Diophantine equation $$k(x+y+z)=xy+xz+yz$$ for a given integer $k$. Here $(x,y,z)=(3,5,41)$ satisfies $x+y+z=7^2$ and $xy+xz+yz=7^3$. Then $(u,v,w)=(1,7,7^2)$ is a natural solution. It should be possible, to use this for a more general solution.

Thank you for highlighting this! This idea gives some solutions to the problem, but I am interested in the case when $$ is a rational number. So, I will try to think to generalize the idea. Maybe, by using similar idea, for a given rational number $$, every solutions of $(++)=++$ can be obtained using some parameters.

In equation $(x+y+z)k=(xy+xz+yz), z$ is given below.
$$z=-(xy-kx-ky)/(x+y-k)$$
Since $z$ must be integer, then  take $y = -x+k+1$ where $x \leq k.$
We get
$$z = x^2-kx-x+k^2+k.$$
We consider quadratic equation in $x$, we have discriminant $D=-3k^2-2k+1<0$ where $k>0.$
Then, $z$ is always a positive integer where $x$ and $k$ are positive integers.
However, if $k = 1, (x,y,z)$ is not distinct, so $k$ must be greater than $1.$
In short, $(x,y,z)=(x, -x+k+1, x^2-kx-x+k^2+k)$ where  $k>1$ and $0< x \leq k.$
Numerical examples:
$k=7: (x,y,z)=(1, 7, 49),(2, 6, 44),(3, 5, 41).$
$k=10: (x,y,z)=(1, 10, 100),(2, 9, 92),(3, 8, 86),(4, 7, 82),(5, 6, 80).$

Addendum
This is a partial solution.
Let assume $k$ is the rational number.
Substitute $k=b/a$ into $(xy+xz+yz)=(x+y+z)k.$ We get
$$z=-(-xya+bx+by)/(-xa-ya+b).$$
We take $b=an-1$ and $y = n-x$ with $x < n,$ then we have
$$z = ax^2-anx+an^2-n.$$
Hence, we get a parametric solution as follows.
$m$ and $n$ are positive integers where $n>2(m+1).$
$$(x,y,z)=(m,n-m,am^2-anm+an^2-n),$$
$$(u,v,w)=(m+1,n-m-1,am^2+(-an+2a)m+an^2-an+a-n).$$
For $(a,m,n)=(2,1,7),$ we have
$(x,y,z,k)=(1, 6, 79, 13/2),(u,v,w,k)=(2, 5, 71, 13/2).$

Though not expilicitly mentioned by Tomita, his answer provides a parametric solution. Namely: (u,v,w)=[(m+1),(k-m),(m^2+k^2-km+m)] & (x,y,z)=[(m),(k-m+1),(m^2-mk+k+k^2-m)]. Where (m,k) are parameters. For (m,k)=(2,7) we have: (x,y,z,u,v,w)=(2,6,44,3,5,41)

Thank you for highlighting this! This idea gives some solutions to the problem, but I am interested in the case when $k$ is a rational number. So, I will try to think to generalize the idea. Maybe, by using similar idea, for a given rational number $k$, every solutions of $k(x+y+z)=xz+yz+xz$ can be obtained using some parameters.
